# How can I get recognized participating in a niche tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been following [mit-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mit-scratch) for a while (one out of 25, but only 36 questions) and feel like I've hardly gotten anything for it. I've answered five questions, and gotten a total of seven votes. [boisvert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704817/boisvert), with 10 answers, only has a score of 11 (and they are good answers).

For example, I spent around half an hour answering [What is the architecture behind Scratch programming blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244208/what-is-the-architecture-behind-scratch-programming-blocks), but it barely got any attention. The one vote on the question is mine, and the answer's upvote is probably from the OP. (Cool question for people interested in creating a parser for a simple language.)
In another case, I answered [In Scratch, how can you split up a string into a list of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552374/in-scratch-how-can-you-split-up-a-string-into-a-list-of-characters), and it went ignored for a few days - nearly inconceivable in popular tags.

Is this just a hazard of participating in a niche tag, or is there something that can be done to bring more attention to this stuff?

Comment: I participate mainly in [casperjs] and [phantomjs]. Although I wouldn't call them niche, but my vote-to-answer ratio is worse than yours. A big part of my rep are accepts. My longest/best answer sits at 2 up-votes. That is indeed strange. A long time has passed since I got Unsung.

Comment: it is impossible to expect 10 upvotes from the question, read by 3 people. As far as you see, people think that the answer to [concatenating strings in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2711579/1090562) is so cool and helpful that it needs 100+ upvotes. But who knows, may be in a few years this mit-scratch will become super popular and hundreds of people would be using it. Then you will get many upvotes :-)

Comment: You've got 6000 rep in nine months. If it is rep you are after, ignore niches.

Comment: The SO system isn't designed to reward people contributing in niches and complaining about that just makes people sound entitled. If someone is not really interested in helping others but it's epeen that they're after then they need to compete in the big tags (e.g. javascript), be first to answer, be quick to downvote others, and above all be correct. In other words treat it like a job not a hobby. All that rep must be worth something. Right?

Comment: There is a ranking of users per tag (depending on the amount of reputation earned on questions with the tag), which is a form of recognition that applies regardless of the tag popularity.

Comment: I do contribute in big tags as well; do you really think i could have accumulated 6k from niches? My question is simply about recognizing niche contributors as well.

Comment: @ClaraOnager I dispute the "be correct" requirement. On popular tags even incorrect answers manage to get upvotes. (And yes, I know the "over time..." argument but counter examples exist.)

Comment: A score of 11 is pretty high.

Comment: @TylerH A score of 11 *over ten answers*.

Comment: Ah, that part was not clear. Still, that's not low for a niche tag. Even a commonly tagged question can have that amount of votes if the question is very specific to a given situation.

Comment: Well I'd say that its not just niches that get hit by this problem. Anecdotally, I've run into many users with insanely high scores asking terrible questions on the C++ tag, who got their reps from the much more popular PHP. I'd like to see a meta analysis of reputation by tag, maybe normalized to number of questions or number of questions with positive scores?

Comment: "Is this just a hazard of participating in a niche tag". Yes. That's the definition of a niche.

Comment: There's _niche_ and then there's _obscure_

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, you could add up the total number of questions on the site, create a ratio between that and your niche tag, and then weight your scores accordingly.

Comment: _Me-honest_ : I don't browse `mit-scratch` tagged questions simply because I don't have even a clue of what's that. _Me-lying_ : I'll check those question and vote accordingly... (_Me-honest again_ : of course I wont : I don't even know if the answer works because I don't even understand the question :/ Sorry)

Comment: Voted for both answers.

Comment: The other side of the coin is that if you participate in a popular tag, it can be hard to get rep because there are already so many people answering questions in that topic.

Answer (score 57):

It is just a hazard of participating in a niche tag. There are just not that many people that read the posts, understand your answer and vote. I participate in several such niche tags (I've written answers to [half the questions in the `zodb` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zodb/topusers)) and the voting patterns are anaemic compared to popular tags. That's just how it is.

If *all* you do is participate in the niche tags, there *is* a badge to encourage you to keep contributing. The [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badges are [aimed squarely at supporting those that answer posts with low-frequency tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/badge-suggestion-unsung-hero-5-accepted-answers-with-no-votes). If your accepted answers don't get upvotes, at least you get a badge!

You already [earned Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious?userid=3187556) for your hard work, you only need another [7 accepted 0-scoring answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45192/how-many-more-accepted-answers-do-i-need-until-tenacious-unsung-hero) to get Unsung Hero. Take into account only answers over 10 days old are taken into consideration.

Comment: I got both these honorary badges but was not aware that they got awarded to low-freq tags. Clicking them does not tell me what tag they were for. 1. Can I find that out? 2. Can I earn more than 1, for other rare tags?

Comment: @Jongware: they are aimed at awarding tireless work in low-frequency tags, but there is no specific tag requirement. I cannot ever earn the badges, for example, I have way too many accepted answers with a positive score.

Comment: Ha! well, now that I've got these two, I guess I should start making good answers :P

Comment: There's also [Tumbleweed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) for the question side of things.

Comment: One can only assume the tag `zodb` is an abbreviation for Zoidberg.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: sorry to [disappoint you](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/zodb/info).

Comment: Nooooooooooo D:

Comment: I got Unsung too, but I don't think I answer in niche tags. I think I just answer unpopular questions in popular tags. :D

Comment: I am also Unsung, and answer in niche tags.  One day, in the distant future, I might qualify for a bronze badge in my top tag - the first one to be awarded perhaps!  Such is life in the frozen wastes on the far distant edges of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 34):

Just a general idea:

Get actual users of that technology to use Stack Overflow.

I would assume that any niche tag has a technology behind it that has users *somewhere* and that there are many more users than are there SO participants at the moment.

If that this has a mailing list or suchlike, try to also put your questions to that mailing list, with a link to the SO question. That way you can advertise the tag on SO, maybe get some users to use SO, and thereby maybe also get some rep.

Comment: This is a good idea. The thing with Scratch is, it already has its own discussion forums, so that gets a lot of activity, and not so much on SO. Also, many Scratch users are underage for SO. :)

Comment: @Scimonster +1 Phrasing it this way feels a bit promotional, but it's what I do, too.  I'm active in a number of "semantic web"-ish tags (RDF, OWL, SPARQL, etc.).  If you look at my profile, you'll see that I've got the first bronze and silver badges in some of those tags.  I see a lot of the questions and answers, and when I see questions on mailing lists that are answered or seen answered on Stack Overflow, I don't hesitate to point the mailing list reader to those questions (along with some localized guidance, too).

Comment: @scimonster you can just lie about your age, like with any site. no big deal.

Comment: Or ... get actual users of Stack Overflow to use that technology!

Answer (score 17):

I participate in a niche tag as well, and it can be frustrating to get basically zero feedback on your hard work. But I've found that my most useful answers continue to accumulate attention, feedback, and yes, reputation, over time.  Good canonical answers will attract attention from search engines and can even have the effect of growing the popularity of the tag here on SO.

You're a pioneer.  If you've chosen a subject that is gaining traction, the recognition of your participation will grow as its popularity does.

Comment: But the question also needs to be good to be found. Therefore it's good that we have the Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator badges to encourage editing the question however small the edit (no too minor reject reason anymore yay).

Comment: Jason is absolutely right.  As a huge contributor to the [selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium/info) tag on SO, I have been contributing solely to that, and it's finally gaining traction.  I am number 3 in answering questions in the tag, but i'm still #9 overall because of traffic, and upvote tendencies.

Answer (score 10):

*but it barely got any attention....*

You shouldn't write answers if you are seeking attention of other users, you write the answer to help OP and others who will come searching for a similar issue.

For example, many times I tend to post answers on old questions because,

- I have a better solution
- Current solutions are outdated
- I love participating on a decent post by answering canonical answers

So obviously my posts won't get attention compared to the answers I post on recently asked questions but after a while the posts on old question helps users the most as it drives in more traffic via search and they appreciate my answers by voting up.

So don't worry if your posts don't get any attention, its the future visitors who will vote and appreciate if your answers will help them fix their issue.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get recognized is to ask about getting recognized in Meta.  Then if you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244208/what-is-the-architecture-behind-scratch-programming-blocks/25226755#25226755) to [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552374/in-scratch-how-can-you-split-up-a-string-into-a-list-of-characters/26566248#26566248) that [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362163/scratch-how-do-i-produce-an-ascii-text-program-listing/25226479#25226479) have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425975/scratch-output-file-txt-or-similar/26449768#26449768) people [will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516493/sprite-disappears-in-scratch-even-when-touching-another-sprite/25516556#25516556) probably [click](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3187556%20%5bmit-scratch%5d) on the links and upvote you for your good answers.  I know I did.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential bad consequence of this effect is that niche tags are unable to self-govern in the way that larger tags can. Fewer users will reach the rep requirements to auto-edit, vote to close or reopen, etc. Getting those thousand upvotes to have auto-delete will be basically impossible. As a result, small tags will disproportionately be ruled by visiting users and moderators.

Answer (score -4):

So i decided to propose a solution on MSE: [Request: reduce Tag Badge requirements for a rare tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84842/request-reduce-tag-badge-requirements-for-a-rare-tag/242761#242761) (answer)

I defined niche tags as tags with 20-400 questions, and no more than a total score of 600 on all of the questions. [17223 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/239256/niche-tags-20-400-questions-maximum-600-total-score) qualified.

Niche-tag-specific badges could be awarded to people who contribute in those tags. I defined a bronze badge as 20 score in 10 answers, and silver as 80 score in 40 answers.

I did not query who would get which badges, but i did create a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/239599/my-niche-tag-score) to see a specific user's niche-tag score, and from there, you can see how many qualify.

Comment: Question count & Total score are numbers that keep increasing, so not sure if they can be used as a param (not that I agree with the niche tag badge concept either). What would happen say if 10 days after a person getting the niche tag badge, the numbers go above the qualifying limit?

Comment: I explained in more detail on MSE, but when the tag graduates, the niche badge would not be lost.

Comment: I did read that mate. What I am trying to say is that every tag starts with a low question count (though even moderately popular existing tags are beyond that count already). So you can't use just that as a qualifying criteria. Maybe something like a question frequency would be a better bet (but even that could improve).

Comment: I'm certainly open to suggestions on improving the criteria. Having a badge not only would reward existing niche-tag participants, but might encourage more people.