# Increased reputation for answering questions in areas of less traffic

Tags: discussion, reputation

This question is about how long it takes to get reputation as someone that provides very good support, but in a less popular language. My research has led me to [How does a new user get started on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) and [Can you become reputable on SO for already popular languages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266121/can-you-become-reputable-on-stackoverflow-for-already-popular-languages). Both assume that you are providing support for popular languages.

Most articles I’ve come across have made the very good point that the best way to develop good reputation is to answer the questions thoroughly and provide some value when doing so, rather than just getting a working one-liner in there before anyone else. So assuming that everyone starts answering this way (which is best for the community), who gets more reputation? Clearly the people in the more popular languages.

Is that fair to the dedicated people helping out with the less popular languages? **I only pose the questions because SO grants privileges based on reputation**, presumably assuming that reputation is a direct measure of dedication. If they want a direct measure of dedication, surely they should increase the reputation available to posters in less popular languages/areas?

Addition:
For clarity, I am not "hunting rep" I am asking from the perspective of being able to enjoy the priveledges of a dedicated user

Comment: `presumably assuming that reputation is a direct measure of dedication` That's a false assumption.

Comment: Unless the majority can see something in it *for them*, this suggestion is not going to be popular. So if SO starts giving out more reputation to good posts in the less popular areas, the minority of folks who are active there will benefit but *what's in it for the majority*?

Comment: Assist others for the sake of help, not worthless rep.

Comment: A thought: If you increase the reputation gain in the less popular tags, it will attract the reputation hunters. If you attract the reputation hunters, the tag will become more popular. Once it becomes popular enough, the rep gain will need to be decreased again, and other tags will draw the rep hunters away. If the rep hunters leave again, the tag will become less popular... I see a cycle that would to be need monitored here. (Not to mention we have no way to foresee if the reputation hunters I mention would give good answers or not.)

Comment: @Omar OP isn't necessarily talking about 'worthless rep'. They're talking about rep which grants privileges. Privileges such as making these comments, approving edits, etc.  Perhaps those privileges should be granted in the low-traffic tags based on something other than rep (assuming that it already isn't).

Comment: Reputation gained from asking and answering is directly proportional to the amount of SO users who think your contributions are valuable. Of course this number of users is higher in areas of the site which are frequented by more users. And no, neither life nor SO is "fair"; nothing you propose could change that.

Comment: @basher I'm active on one tag only and it's not too popular as others. When I started answering questions, I hit 2k rep in 2 months and I never thought I would hit 20k. You still can do moderation without full moderation privileges. OP should be patient, good things take time :)

Comment: @Omar Yup. Was just playing devils advocate. I don't care either way :)

Comment: Dup? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275468/how-can-i-get-recognized-participating-in-a-niche-tag

Comment: looks at SharePoint stats and then come again. 3k rep and in second page of the top user league???

Comment: Both low-traffic tags and high-traffic tags have their own challenges. In low-traffic ones you will get less views but there is less competition/fastest-gun-in-the-westers. It can be more rewarding to answer these questions. In a more popular tag it can be harder to get attention on your answers because so many other users are answering. Also, people on these tags tend to be harsher. Pick your battles.

Comment: we don't need more rep, just privileges levels recalculated for the site we are on.

Answer (score 12):

If you are a reputation hunter, simply stick to the popular tags. Oh, and answering fast and correctly would help too.

Answer less frequented tags to *actually help*. Answer the question and know that you made someone's day easier. That's the actual goal of answering, really.

And in the long run, those great answers may even help others, and you'll get the upvotes. Answering posts in the less-frequented tags requires patience and actual dedication. Provided your answer is actually useful, of course.

Sure, it is not ideal, but most privileges you need to care about can be had for a few thousand reputation points.

Your alternative, to give more points to upvotes to 'slow' tags is not fair and won't work, for several reasons. First of all, reputation here is based on voting, and for voting to work fairly, you need a larger audience, not votes that vary in power by audience size. Why should fewer people get to decide that you have earned a privilege, *just* because the tag is not as popular?

And larger vote values would attract the wrong type of answer; the low quality reputation hunting type of answers that just want to reap those extra points. And this in areas where there already is less attention to weed out low-quality dross!

Comment: Your answer should be "_Be Patient!_"

Comment: To make it clear: I am asking from the perspective of someone who is here to **actually help** but realising it will take me longer to enjoy priveledges as someone *actually helping* in a less popular area

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But there are always going to be slow and fast ways to privileges, but skewing the balance only leads to unfairness and reputation vampires posting low-quality answers in areas with less oversight.

Comment: damn, when I'll see 300k under your name?!

Comment: @nicael: patience, my young padawan, patience!

Comment: I see 300k under your name :D but when you'll reach 300k?

Comment: @nicael: Patience comes to those who wait, young grasshopper.

Comment: Yay, u haz 300k!!!

Comment: @nicael: I can haz 300k.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation could be awarded by tag instead of simply being a "you have rep or you don't" type of thing. Then your rep for tags that get less attention would mean more in context. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to translate that to a weighted system without all sorts of tag abuse cropping up. "Hey, I answered the only question in the Implementing Java in Assembly tag that I just created! SO MUCH REP."

Comment: You can see a user's total score in a tag from their profile, or from the tag page.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to add my own answer to the mix, then.

I do enjoy giving for the sake of giving. However, waiting for ages to get enough rep to enjoy the website more/ continue enjoying giving in a small, niche, area is de-motivating. This is exacerbated when you see people getting plenty of rep in high activity areas for similarly good-quality posts. I stand by this point.

**The solution:** *There is none*. Because too many of the people who have enough rep to make the differences happen are too self righteous that when someone, who is genuinely bringing value to the community, opens a discussion about the rep system, most of them make no effort to relate to OP and OP gets **shunned** and **downvoted** into oblivion.

Here's an interesting example: if someone in my position asks the question "[How can I get noticed in a niche tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275468/how-can-i-get-recognized-participating-in-a-niche-tag)" users will relish telling them to be patient, and tell you "It's a hazard of participating in a Niche tag". You'll get upvoted 34 times. However, if you open a question about possible ways to change so that people like us don't lose motivation with the system, you get downvoted 10+ times.

I have spent the past few months contributing good answers to Excel and VBA tags. I'm sure if you asked the top rep users in those tags they would tell you I've even taught them a few things as well. I had every intention of sticking it out and slowly bleeding the rep out of the system so that I can enjoy edit and moderating tools. I was just asking the question on behalf of anyone else who is/will be in my position.

This community is built on it's contributors, and if some of the people at the top swan around making genuine contributors (regardless of current rep) feel like their opinion isn't worth anything, you will eventually lose your contributors.

So after this post gets further shunning, I'll be deleting my account. One less expert in your Niche/less-popular areas.

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming that your question's votes are a reflection of your reputation.  It's a reflection of the content, phrasing, and tone of your question.  There are constructive and non-constructive ways of making very similar points, and they will greatly affect a post's score, far, far more than the reputation of the author.

Comment: And another note: It's not just high-rep users telling you this is a bad idea. I have even less rep than you. Rep has nothing to do with this. It would create more problems than it would solve. For an example of that, see my comment under the question.